# Glass photograph

Tags: exposure

I have a photograph of I think my great grandmother over150 years old it is on glass not stuck on. She is sitting down and looks to have a false arm but I think it will be with her sitting in one position for a long time.  The image.seems to be inside the glass.  Is there anywhere I can take it to see if it is worth anything. I live near Leeds Yorkshire

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about valuation of old photographs, not the actual process of making photos.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - Maybe I missed it, but where in the help section or meta does it say that sort of question is off topic and only the process of making photos is?

Comment: JoanneC: I was maybe a bit overly general in my comment, but which one of the [things you should ask about](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) do you think this one falls under?

Comment: @PhilipKendall - I think you may be missing the point: it's not listed as off topic and the on topic list isn't expected to be exhaustive. In any event, "the process of making photos" is not the sum scope of our site, it includes history, societal impact, and has even included things like pricing in the past.

Comment: Also, I would suggest that the valuation of photographs, regardless of age, is of relevant interest to photographers...

Comment: I accept that "the process of making photos" is too specific - but I don't think that means we need to make every "is this photo I found worth something?" question on-topic. "How to preserve old photos": entirely on-topic. I'd be dubious about a general "which photos are worth something" question (too opinion-based), and I'd say that "where can I take a specific old photo to get it valued in Yorkshire" isn't going to add much for future visitors of the site. You disagree, at least one other person agrees with me :-)

Comment: grr... iPad selection, ignore chat request... :) Anyways, @PhillipKendall, if you can review the history of the review queues, you would find that I'm not alone either.

Comment: I think "is old photo X worth something" isn't likely to be a repeated problem because the answer is invariably going to be "no", so any future ones we get can just be duplicates. :) But I'm also optimistic that Margaret would like to learn more about the photo and its process and history...

Answer (score 3):

I can tell you right now: unless your great-grandmother was famous in some way, it has very little monetary value. Not worth the fuel costs of getting somewhere to evaluate it, probably.

But what a wonderful family artifact! It's not like you can go snap another one, at least not without inventing a time machine. In that way, it is priceless.

We can help identify the type of photograph this might be, and what steps you should take to insure its preservation. Is it a positive or negative image? Does it look the same from every angle? What color / tint is it?  (Silver or brownish or bluish?) Do you have any information about what year it might be from?